# PHP DOM functions reading line number from input file

Tags: php, dom

I have a program which reads an XML file using the DOM functions:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->load("myFile.xml");
```

As I traverse the nodes in this document, is there a way to tell which line of the input file the node was defined on?

For example:

```
1: <!-- myFile.xml -->
2: <foobar>
3:     <foo>FOO</foo>
4:     <bar>BAR</bar>
5: </foobar>
```

and the PHP:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$bars = $xp->query("//bar");
$myBar = $bars[0];
echo "The first <bar> element is on line " . performMagicHere(); // 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$element->getLineNo()` will return the line number of the opening tag. Note: for opening tags that span more than one line, it will return the end of the opening tag. It doesn't seem to work for DOMText nodes though (returns 0).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php

Comment: Excellent! Note that this is for PHP 5.3.0+ only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this with PHP's DOM class. DOM Level 3 [added support for this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#DOMLocator-line-number), but we don't have DOM level 3 support in PHP yet.